# When I use dplyr::filter and a sequence command it randomly skips rows it shouldn't

Tags: r, dplyr

When I use dplyr::filter with a sequence and %in% it randomly leaves out rows that it shouldn't. Is there a better way to filter the data so that I reliably get a df that includes every value of q from 0.01 to 1 by steps of 0.01?

Here is a snippet of my data to create `df`

```
df <- structure(list(q = c(0.0495185253755619, 0.05, 0.0532000452215362, 
0.0569525370086692, 0.06, 0.0646716714872386, 0.07, 0.0767903072707, 
0.08, 0.0809750285664481, 0.09, 0.0939688126826123, 0.1, 0.103000546236258, 
0.11, 0.117107570056396), r_timestamp = structure(c(1403667900, 
NA, 1403668800, 1403669700, NA, 1403670600, NA, 1403671500, NA, 
1403672400, NA, 1403673300, NA, 1403674200, NA, 1403675100), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Etc/GMT-4"), NO3_rise = c(0.0482379790550339, 
NA, 0.0482408804822149, 0.0496608873041167, NA, 0.0510808941260188, 
NA, 0.053096735586062, NA, 0.0551125770461051, NA, 0.0559331273472383, 
NA, 0.0567536776483717, NA, 0.0531344453067981)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code. The resulting `df2` should have 7 rows and a `q` value for 0.05 to 0.11 by steps of 0.01. The code currently returns `df2` with only 4 lines including `q` values of 0.05, 0.08, 0.09, 0.11.

```
# Packages
 library("tidyverse")
 library("lubridate")
 library("zoo")

# Code chunk
  df2 <- df %>% 
    # Interpolate missing solute values
    mutate_at(vars(c(NO3_rise)),
              funs(na.approx(., x = q, xout = q, na.rm = FALSE))) %>% 
    # Only keep rows where q value matches sequence below
    filter(q %in% seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01))
```

Comment: It's impossible to help without being able to reproduce your problem. Instead of all that code, can you use `dput` to share a minimal example of your dataframe that reproduces this issue? My best guess would be that `q` is a floating point number, so you have values that appear to be, for example, `0.02`, but are actually (due to floating point rounding errors in however they were generate) something like `0.0200000000001`

Comment: To add to @divibisan's comment: give us a sample of what goes into the `group_by` at the very end. We probably only need the last 5 lines to debug, not a whole 63 lines. You mark checking that `q` matches a step above—you might be better off filtering against a lag or something

Comment: I've answered to explain this problem in detail, but really it could be considered a duplicate of: [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue caused by [floating point precision problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal). Let's look at the 5th row:

```
df$q[5]
[1] 0.06

df$q[5] == 0.06
[1] TRUE

df$q[5] %in% seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01)
[1] FALSE
```

Why? Let's look at its **real** value. While R rounds it to 0.06, the actual value is slightly lower due to floating point rounding errors:

```
sprintf("%.54f",df$q[5])
[1] "0.059999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375"

# It's the same as how R represents 0.06
sprintf("%.54f",0.06)
[1] "0.059999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375"

# But when made by seq, the number is different!
sprintf("%.54f",seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01)[6])
[1] "0.060000000000000004718447854656915296800434589385986328"
```

So what can you do? The safe option is to use `all.equal`, which matches with an allowed tolerance designed to work with floating point numbers. Here's a (likely unoptimized) way to use `all.equal` to compare 2 vectors in the same way as `%in%`:

```
fp_all_equal <- function(x, y) {
    as.logical(colSums(sapply(x, function(x) as.logical(mapply(all.equal, x, y))), na.rm = T))
}

fp_all_equal(df$q, seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01))
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Another option is to avoid using `seq` with floating point numbers, since it seems to calculate them slightly differently than other R functions. I can't explain why (and I don't promise that this will always work), but if you make an *integer* sequence with `seq` and then divide it by 100 with `/`, using `%in%` will work:

```
df$q %in% (seq(1,100)/100)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```